# Retirar espaços nos campos input

Tags: javascript, css

Colegas.

Tenho um formulário do qual gostaria que o usuário ao copiar uma determinada palavra e colar no campo input, retire os espaços entre a frase ou palavra copiada automaticamente. Teria algum meio no CSS ou Javascript?

Comment: Você quer colocar máscara no input?

Comment: Podes explicar melhor _"uma determinada palavra"_?

Comment: Não seria exatamente uma máscara. Uma determinada palavra ou frase, onde o usuário ao copiar por exemplo o endereço de um Word e colar no campo input de um formulário, automaticamente excluísse os espaços que criou antes ou depois da palavra ou frase.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assim:

```
<input type="text" id="t" />

<script>
var $t = document.getElementById('t');
$t.addEventListener('paste', function(event) {
  setTimeout(function(){
    this.value = this.value.replace(/\s+/g, '');
  }.bind(this), 0)
});
</script>
```

edit: 
Se quiser apenas os espaços antes e depois, basta trocar a regex por:

```
.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '')
```

Comment: Perfeito William. Funcionou. Muito obrigado.

Comment: @Fox.11 tinhas escrito _"automaticamente excluísse os espaços que criou antes ou depois da palavra ou frase."_... este código apaga **todos** os espaços em brancos. É isso que queres?

Comment: editei, adicionando a regex para apagar apenas antes e depois

Comment: Qual a finalidade do `$` na declaração da varável?

Comment: boas práticas, o $ serve para identificar uma variável que aponta para um objeto DOM.

Answer (score 4):

Baseado [nessa resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11944089/3846228), podemos ver que utilizando HTML e JS é possível. 
Veja como:

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" id="telefone" maxlength="10" />​
```

**JavaScript**

```
var telefone = document.getElementById('telefone'),
    limparEspacos;

limparEspacos= function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var pastedText = '';
    if (window.clipboardData && window.clipboardData.getData) { // IE
        pastedText = window.clipboardData.getData('Text');
      } else if (e.clipboardData && e.clipboardData.getData) {
        pastedText = e.clipboardData.getData('text/plain');
      }
    this.value = pastedText.replace(/\D/g, '');
};

telefone.onpaste = limparEspacos;
```

---

Lembrando que o [regex](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp) responsável por remover os espaços encontra-se nessa linha:

```
this.value = pastedText.replace(/\D/g, '');
```

Ou seja, caso queira alterar algum outro caracter, deve-se alterar a máscara `/\D/g` , dentro de `.replace(/\D/g, '');` para coincidir com os caracteres desejados.

Answer (score 3):

É possível usar o evento `paste`. Então separar por espaços e então juntar sem eles:

```js
function removerEspacos(e) {
  var clipboardData, pastedData;

  e.stopPropagation();
  e.preventDefault();

  clipboardData = e.clipboardData || window.clipboardData;
  pastedData = clipboardData.getData('Text');

  document.getElementById('entrada').value = pastedData.split(' ').join('');
}

document.getElementById('entrada').addEventListener('paste', removerEspacos);
```

```html
<input id="entrada" />
```

Comment: Obrigado a todos

Answer (score 2):

```js
var input = document.querySelector('input');
var palavras = ['palavra1', 'palavra2'];

function limpar() {
  var self = this;
  palavras.forEach(function(palavra) {
    var regex = new RegExp('\\s*' + palavra + '\\s*', 'g');
    self.value = self.value.split(regex).join(palavra);
  });
}

input.addEventListener('keyup', limpar);
input.addEventListener('paste', limpar);

/* Texto para testar:

Olá este texto tem a palavra1 no meio.

Este texto tem a palavra2, e também a palavra1 misturadas.

*/
```

```css
input {
  width: 300px;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<input>
```

A ideia do código é: cada vez que houver `paste` ou `keyup` ele corre a função `limpar` que procura no input por cada palavra com ou sem espaço antes e depois no texto. Caso encontre retira o espaço e junta a palavra ao que havia antes e depois, tirando os espaços.